# How to execute python script using python command

Tags: python, pycharm

When I execute a python script in the Pycharm IDE, It executes the script with the path to the python executable like so:
`path/to/python/executable path/to/the/script/foo.py`

Is there a way to execute it with the python command like: `python3 path/to/the/script/foo.py`?

I know that it makes no difference, and I know that I can just type in the command in the Terminal but I want it to be executed by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+F10` (the shortcut key for executing the script) or by pressing the "run" button.

Comment: If you want to change the python it's using, you can set the Project Interpreter in Settings -> Project:...

Comment: What is the problem with calling the full path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, with your project opened, click edit configurations as image 1 shows.
[Edit configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XCbO.png)

Image 1:

In the opened window you can change Run configurations

Comment: but it doesn't have any option that executes with the command

Comment: This option is called `Additional options`, under main configuration panel

Comment: maybe it doesn't exist on linux version
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 with Pycharm installed from snap

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to run it specifically like that?
If you wish to use some system interpreter, then you can just [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html) it in PyCharm and use to run all of your scripts or only specific ones.
So in case you want to use **Interpreter A** as your project interpreter and **Interpreter B** to run some script, then just configure that **Interpreter B** in PyCharm and set it in Run/Debug configuration.